# How can I update a particular data and delete the previous stored data before updating(mongodb with nest js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I want to update a data by its id but before update i want to delete the previously stored data on that same id.What would be the process?

controller.ts

```
   public updateVendorServiceSpecialPrice = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> => {
    try {
        if (req.body.vendorServiceId!='') {
            let results = await this.ServicesService.updateVendorServicesSpecialPrice(req.params.vendorServiceId, req.body);
            if (results != false) {
                this.success(res, 'Updated Successfully', 200, results._id);
            }
        } 
        return await this.error(res, 'Something Went Wrong!.', 500);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
    public async updateVendorServicesSpecialPrice(
    vendorServiceId: any,
    data: any
): Promise<any | Error> {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            vendorServiceSpecialPriceSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
                vendorServiceId,
                { ...data },
                (err: any, success: any) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    if (!success) {
                        resolve(false);
                    } else {
                        resolve(success);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('service error\n', e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I am trying in this way to solve this,may be I am wrong,what would br the right process:

```
    public async updateVendorServicesSpecialPrice(
    vendorServiceId: any,
    data: any
): Promise<any | Error> {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            vendorServiceSpecialPriceSchema.deleteOne({vendorServiceId})
            vendorServiceSpecialPriceSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
                vendorServiceId,
                { ...data },
                { returnNewDocument: true },
                (err: any, success: any) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    if (!success) {
                        resolve(false);
                    } else {
                        resolve(success);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('service error\n', e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time....

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOneAndReplace method from mongoose:

```
vendorServiceSpecialPriceSchema.findOneAndReplace(
  { _id: new Types.ObjectId(vendorServiceId) }, // You need to import Types from mongoose module
  data,
  (err: any, success: any) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    if (!success) {
      resolve(false);
    } else {
      resolve(success);
    }
  }
);
```

If _id is not present in your data object just added:

```
{_id: vendorServiceId, ...data}
```

Comment: no,I want to do it manually like I want to delete the previous data first then update that

Comment: ..      ......@Tom Slabbaert

Comment: You can do it manually by first using `deleteOne` and then executing the update. but it sounds like findoneandreplace with an upsert fits better here as you can save an operation. is there a reason why you want to manually execute the deletion?

Comment: reason is if I am not getting the record against which I am updating at that time it will not create any error for me,I mean if that record is deleted for any circumstances so....

Comment: and vendorServiceId is the common id for all record: https://prnt.sc/len1Bk6tnWol      @Tom Slabbaert

Comment: how I do it anually @Tom Slabbaert